# How to Create your own Domain Name after forwarded my server through my router?

Tags: ubuntu, router, dns, apache-http-server, ubuntu-server

I have set up my own web server with Ubuntu server 16.04, I am actually using another laptop for testing the web server.

To have access locally, I have:

---

```
      Router     192.168.1.1
      Server     192.168.1.6
      My PC      192.168.1.5
```

---

After installing everything necessary `samba, apache2, webmin, mySQL, etc...` through Terminal -- sometimes through `ssh root@192.168.1.6` in *My PC* and sometimes directly in the Terminal of the server.

Now, when I browse `192.168.1.6` through `Chrome`, I actually can see the apache home page. *`everything here seems successful`*.

Then, I create my own web and save it in `var/www/html/mywebsite/index.html` and I can access it locally under any browser by `http://192.168.1.6/mywebsite/index.html`.

Finally, now I want to access this website from outside. So, I try to spend sometime how to do it and I finally find an answer by forwarding it.
Then, I went to the browser and typed `192.168.1.1` which is the `router IP` -- the brand is *`fronter`*. So, I went there and forwarded my `web server` that has the ip `192.168.1.6`.
So, after I did that, in order to access it outside, I need to know the `web server public ip address`.

Then, I did this to get the server public ip

> ~$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
>
> 50.104.113.XXX

Now, when I browse this `50.103.114.XXX` i can see the *apache home page* and `50.104.113.XXX/mywebsite/index.html` for *my website*.

### The Problem begin here

But then, I want to change this `50.104.113.XXX` into *domain name* ==> `domainname.com`. I want to create my own domain name, without leaning on or going anywhere like ***GoDaddy or any other website*** and spend money to get one.

I did so many researches, read the ***ubuntu server guide***, watching so many tutorial, and forums. But, I am totally stuck. I tried to set up by using `Bind`, `DNS`, `apache` inside **`webmin`**. But, it's not working.

Here is the thing that I did step by step by using apache:

```
//I access my server through *My PC*
~$ sudo ssh root@192.168.1.6

//Mode superUser
~$ sudo -i

~$ nano /etc/hosts
```

> 127.0.0.1       localhost
>
> 127.0.1.1       root.home   root

// I added this:

> 0.0.0.0         domainname.com

But, this only work on the computer I added it ( for example if I did this in the actual file inside *My PC* it working) but if it's on the web server it is not accessible.

So, I tried something more:

```
~$ sudo cp /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.com.conf

~$ sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/domainname.com.conf
```

I change `<VirtualHost *:80>` into

> `<VirtualHost domainname.com:80>`

And, also uncommented `#ServerName www.example.com` and changer into this:

> ServerName www.domainname.com
>   ServerName domainname.com
>
> ServerAdmin root@domainname.com

then, `~$ sudo service apache2 reload`

`~$ sudo a2ensite www.domainname.com.conf`
`~$ sudo a2ensite domainname.com.conf`

`~$ sudo service apache2 restart`

After doing this, it's still not working.

So, I tried the **`Webmin`** option by using the **`DNS`** and **`BIND`**. **But all of them are still not working.**

It is fine for me if I need to buy some materials or hardware to setup my web server. Please, help me if you know.

***Knowledge is such a wealthy thing to have***. *Thanks in advance*

Comment: I don’t understand your question. Do you want to have a legitimate domain name that people can use to access your website? If so, you HAVE to buy and register a domain name. Typically it will include free DNS hosting. There is not any way for you to create your own domain name for free.

Comment: I want to get a domain name that everyone can access. I already forwarded my web server, and i have access to it but I want to get a domain name. But, since you said it is impossible unless I buy and register

Comment: Do you know, how the system works? like how do these people create their website and get people to register their domain name through their website. Like what do I need to buy to build one of those company like `GoDaddy` and the other site

Comment: You can’t. You would have to be a registrar and trying to do so would be impossible for an individual and exceedingly complicated and expensive. Just buy the $12 domain name and do it like everyone else does.

Comment: If you could do it individually, how many competing `google.com` domains would there be? The central authorities are required to insure unicity. You are also paying to prevent someone else from usurping your domain name. Maybe you want something like a [dynamic DNS](https://www.noip.com/)

Comment: @appleoddity There are a handful of CCTLDs which offer free domains, for example .tk

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "In the general case, you can't".  Domain names are controlled by registrars who charge for these, and you need to go through one in order to get your domain DNS added to the appropriate root/tld/cctld/similar nameservers.

If you have someone with a domain, you can ask them to delegate a subdomain - so for example if they owned example.com you could ask them to point prince.example.com to you (or delegate it to your nameservers)

That said, there are/were some free domain names you can get - I know ".tk" was offering free domains (and there appear to be a few others as well), and believe they still do.  I've not used them, but have a look at freenom.com and see if you can get something you can live with.

You may (or may not) need to find nameservers to host them on, depending on if your registrar can do this for you.  If they can't, you need to have a minimum 2 nameservers set up on different IP addresses (ie external IP addresses, so you would need a system in addition to your own to be compliant.)